# Jenkins + Active Directory Authentication - Slow Login

Tags: active-directory, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins master running on Windows 2008 SP2 set up with Active Directory authentication. The authentication is working fine and normally there is no issue with Login. 
Occasionally however Jenkins will take 4 to 5 minutes to log a user in. This seems to correlate with the amount of time a user has been inactive (i.e. A user who has not logged in for 2 or 3 weeks will experience extremely slow response when trying to log in).

Has anyone else experienced this behavior? I'm really not sure if I should start looking at active directory or Jenkins to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin maintainers actively suggest to [enable logging](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Active+Directory+plugin) (using "hudson.plugins.active_directory" to ALL) and file a bug if a problem happens.

Comment: I'm using the AD plugin already...Not sure what you are trying to say here. The plugin maintainers aren't going to be able to help with random performance issues that most likely have nothing to do with their plugin.

Comment: Enabling logging will allow you to obtain timed events of the auth conversation between your jenkins server and your AD server. That should give you a head start to troubleshoot further.

BTW, plugin maintainers may help you out. I added tracking of upload speed for a file distribution plugin to help troubleshoot some users.

Comment: I see, I misunderstood your answer initially. You had said "enable login" but I think you meant "enable logging"? I have edited your answer to reflect this. In that case yes, that's a good idea. I still have to manage to collect the logs on one of the rare occasions when this happens though.

Comment: I mentioned jenkins logs because they are probably the easiest to setup and to get an idea of. In the end to solve your issue you will probably have to do more troubleshooting at the network level. The problems could range from network misconfigurations (DNS, time desynchronization, ipv6, AD address) or more AD specific issues. I've found this read to be interesting: http://blogs.technet.com/b/instan/archive/2008/04/17/troubleshooting-the-intermittent-slow-logon-or-slow-startup.aspx  Hopefully your issue is just time sync, because I believe that would be the easiest to fix ;) good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins slow login with Active directory seens to be almost alway's related to DNS issue. Check your dns Service (srv), NS, DomainDnsZones, _ldap.tcp.domaine.com, _gc._tcp.domaine.com and ForestDnsZone response from your AD/DNS server. If you can't reach all ip/port listed, you will face some random slow loggin (30 or 60 seconds, depend on the query) when the jenkins AD pluggins will try to query those servers/services.

You can easly trap the dns query with tcpdump or wireshark on your jenkin's server or on the DNS server.

tcpdump -i interface port 53

specifying sites can help you to make a potable workaround as that will limit slow loging to only bad result when querying inexistant/unreachable ip/port return by ForestDnsZone.